# Follow Sharepoint site via Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to use Powershell to manage which users follow a Sharepoint Online site. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: what you want, follow a site using powershell or getting the list of user who follow a site?

Comment: I'll have to join Waqas here. Currently, your question is a bit unclear... could you please try to edit it and add some more info on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking is, you want to follow a site in sharepoint on behalf of another user (privileged user)  (correct me if i am wrong here, this is me just assuming :) ).

This is unfortunately not possible in SharePoint online because the APIs(CSOM,REST,JSOM,PowerShell) needed to make it work are not exposed/available. This is possible in SharePoint On-Premise though(using SSOM), but that's not useful for your issue.

So, only using a user's account(current user) can you follow a site in SharePoint online.

Reference (check table - API for common tasks for following content in SharePoint) - [Follow content in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/follow-content-in-sharepoint#common-programming-tasks-for-following-content-in-sharepoint)

Comment: @niklasalden - did you find the answer helpful ? If yes, could you please mark it as answer :) Thanks !